# Replace a substring with another value in a main string

Tags: bash, sed, string

I have a string with a below pattern

```
SrcWorkspaceName=abc_1234;SrcEndVer=1409;Lang=ENU,FRA,NLD
```

I need the `SrcEndVer` value to be replaced from `1409` with other number.

Here the number is stored in a variable,say

```
Var=1600
```

So, `1409` value should be replaced with a variable `Var`

Like the output as below for example

```
SrcWorkspaceName=abc_1234;SrcEndVer=1600;Lang=ENU,FRA,NLD
```

Comment: Please suggest why it was marked as negative, so that i can improve next time or at least i can update this question. I believe I have provided relevant information.

Comment: Welcome! As per your comment, add the crucial information that 1600 is a variable, [edit] the post.

Comment: Updated the question, Please review it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possibility:

```
sed 's/;SrcEndVer=[0-9]*/;SrcEndVer=1600/'
```

Output:

```
SrcWorkspaceName=abc_1234;SrcEndVer=1600;Lang=ENU,FRA,NLD
```

Comment: Actually 1600 is a not fixed number here, instead a variable, So i replaced with variable like this.. 

suppose Var=1600.... then sed 's/;SrcEndVer=[0-9]*/;SrcEndVer='$Var'/' 
and it worked

Answer (score 0):

As no other information is provided I would try the following sed command.

`sed -i -e 's/\(.*;SrcEndVer=\)[^;]*\(;.*\)/\11600\2/' file.txt`

Whereby `file.txt` would be a file containing your string.

s is the substitute command for sed.
s/pattern1/pattern2/ will replace pattern1 with pattern2
`\(xxx\)` is a back reference which will be referenced with a number e.g. \1

sed will put in the first back reference \(.*;SrcEndVer=\) everything before and including ;SrcEndVer= `SrcWorkspaceName=abc_1234;SrcEndVer=`
then [^;]* as many characters which are not ';' `1409`
and in the second back reference \( the next ';' and .*\) the rest of the line `;Lang=ENU,FRA,NLD`.

sed will replace this with the first back reference \1 `SrcWorkspaceName=abc_1234;SrcEndVer=` then 1600 and the second back reference \2 `;Lang=ENU,FRA,NLD`.

Which will give you:
`SrcWorkspaceName=abc_1234;SrcEndVer=1600;Lang=ENU,FRA,NLD`

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) with the [DKVP: Key-value pairs](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/file-formats.html#DKVP:_Key-value_pairs) format:

```
$ echo 'SrcWorkspaceName=abc_1234;SrcEndVer=1409;Lang=ENU,FRA,NLD' | 
    mlr --dkvp --fs ';' put '$SrcEndVer = 1600'
SrcWorkspaceName=abc_1234;SrcEndVer=1600;Lang=ENU,FRA,NLD
```

Comment: sorry to say, but I do not have mlr installed in our unix server.